# From Bose-Hubbard model to quantum rotor model

Tags: condensed-matter, models

For the Bose-Hubbard model:
$$H=-t\sum_{\langle i,j \rangle}(b_i^{\dagger}b_j+b_j^{\dagger}b_i)+K\sum_{i}(\hat{n}-n_0)^2$$
In the large-filling limit, we can replace $\hat{n}$ by $\hat{n}+n_0$, and also $\hat{n}_j$ by $-i\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}$, after the which the on-site repulsion term in the Hamiltonian becomes the kinetic term for the phase angle.

However, for the hopping term, why can we simply replace $b_j^{\dagger}$ with $e^{i\theta_j}$? Basically, we are supposed to get the final phase-only quantum rotor model given as the following:
$$H=-2t\sum_{\langle i,j \rangle}cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)+K\sum_j\left(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\right)^2$$

Source: Eq.(14.3) from "advanced solid state physics 2e" by P. Philips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be slightly more careful: you can always rewrite a bosonic operator $b$ in terms of number and phase variables:
$$
b^{\dagger} = \sqrt{\hat{n}} e^{i \hat{\phi}}
$$
Here the operator $e^{i \hat{\phi}}$ is defined by its action on every occupation number state:
$$
e^{i \hat{\phi}} | n \rangle = | n+1 \rangle
$$
Strictly speaking, $e^{i \hat{\phi}}$ is not unitary since $e^{-i \hat{\phi}} |0 \rangle = 0$. But we can formally extend our Hilbert space to include both positive and negative integers and define $e^{-i \hat{\phi}} |0 \rangle = |-1 \rangle$, at which point $e^{i \hat{\phi}}$ can be properly considered a unitary operator. $\hat{\phi}$ is technically not a well-defined Hermitian operator since it is a compact variable, but formally writing $[\hat{\phi}, \hat{n}] = i$ produces the correct commutation relations for properly defined periodic functions of $\hat{\phi}$, such as $e^{i \hat{\phi}}$.

Now, to obtain the rotor model, what you should do is write $b^{\dagger}_i b_j = 2\sqrt{\hat{n}_i} \cos(\hat{\phi}_i - \hat{\phi}_j) \sqrt{\hat{n}_j}$. Then, if $\langle\hat{n}_i \rangle = \bar{n}$ is large, we can formally replace $\sqrt{\hat{n}_i} = \sqrt{\bar{n} + \delta \hat{n}_i} \simeq \sqrt{\bar{n}}$ to obtain a rotor model of the form
$$
\hat{H} = -2t \bar{n} \sum_{\langle i j \rangle} \cos(\hat{\phi}_i - \hat{\phi}_j) + K \sum_i \delta \hat{n}_i^2
$$
Note the factor of $\bar{n}$ in front. If your goal is to describe the Bose-Hubbard model and not the rotor model, this factor is important: it tells you that the Mott transition is somewhere around $t\bar{n} / K \sim \mathcal{O}(1)$, which suggests that the transition happens at smaller and smaller $t$ as the filling is increased (which is the correct prediction).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace $b^{\dagger}_{j}$ with $e^{i\theta_{j}}$ because the Hamiltonian (real) remains the same under this change. It can seen as follows
(assuming $\theta_{i}$ and $\theta_{j}$ commute) --

$b^{\dagger}_{i}b_{j} + b^{\dagger}_{j}b_{i} = e^{i\theta_{i}}e^{-i\theta_{j}} + e^{i\theta_{j}}e^{-i\theta_{i}}$ = 2$\mathbb{R}~( e^{i(\theta_{i} - \theta_{j})})$ = 2 $\cos(\theta_{i} - \theta_{j})$

Comment: but how can be sure this $\theta\equiv -i\mathrm{log}b^{\dagger}$ is the same phase variable conjugate to particle number?

Comment: I mean, even if it is restricted to $[0,2\pi)$,  it still doesn't  necessarily imply it's the same phase variable.

Comment: also, another problem is it seems to assume the modulus of $b^{\dagger}$ is 1.